# Adding jQuery Validation to Jetstrap via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jetstrap

As of right, now Jetstrap doesn't include jquery.validate as a plugin.
I know they're already working on a feature for users add external `JS/CSS`, but in the mean time I'd like to find a temporary fix.

I've tried to import from a hosted source dynamically by using a few scripts, but none of my approaches have worked so far.

Example (yes, crude but..):

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js';
     (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

Max, one of the creators of Jetstrap posted on Stack 2 days ago about loading scripts dynamically, but his solution for datepicker, and they don't exactly work the same way...

Here's his example:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.2/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', function() {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
})
```

Any creativeness I've had today to deal with problems has dried up, so does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't they work the same way? His script simply runs on document ready, and retrieves the script. All you have to do is run your validator within the success function of the `$.getScript()`

Comment: Adam - feel free to email me at max@jetstrap.com and I can help you and also get your feedback on a few things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohgodwhy's suggestion worked, here's my final code, please use it if you'd like to do the same on Jetstrap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js', function() {
        $("#RegistrationForm").validate({
            rules: { 
            "data[User][email]": {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            "data[User][password]": { 
                required: true, 
                minlength: 8,
                mypassword : true
            }, 
            "data[User][confirm_password]": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#UserPassword'
            } 
        }, 
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
            .text('OK').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
})
```

Comment: Ok, who's the guy that thought it'd be a good idea to make us have to wait 2 days to be able to accept our own answer.